# improve performance with jparepository save method

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data

I am using `<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities)` of `jparepository` class to save thousand of records to db table.

I have tried below code to insert 10K records in db table and it took more than 5 minutes

```
save(listOfObject);
```

I thought with the save method it should have flushed the reocrds with batches however when I saw the table records werent getting committed in batches however got committed at the end (when it reached to 10000th record).

Also when I process these records and insert to another table, then it throws:

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.booleanOp(SqlGeneratorBase.java:3185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.booleanExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:903)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.booleanOp(SqlGeneratorBase.java:3216)

I am using MySql

Any suggestion on improving this.